# URL manipulations in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a code which generates a URL which is like this: `#{URI.escape p.url(checkout_path)}`

Now I need to check a condition where, if `#{URI.escape p.url(checkout_path)}` generates a URL = "http://mywebsite.com" then append /trunk to the end so it must be "http://mywebsite.com/trunk" else if it already has /trunk appended from before then it should be "http://mywebsite.com".

Thus finally if http://mywebsite.com then http://mywebsite.com/trunk

elsif

http://mywebsite.com/trunk then http://mywebsite.com

But I want to know how to do it using `#{URI.escape p.url(checkout_path)}`

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I understood you totally but maybe it will help: `URI.escape(p.url(checkout_path)).include?('trunk')` tells you if the URL contains 'trunk'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would throw this in a helper method somewhere, but you could effectively do something like this:

```
 URI.escape(p.url(checkout_path)) =~ /\/trunk$/ ? URI.escape(p.url(checkout_path)).gsub('/trunk', '') : "#{URI.escape(p.url(checkout_path))}/trunk"
```

Comment: Thanks that should lead me close.